# How do I fix AR.js gltf models jittering/shaking when projected to an <a-nft> image target? / How do I properly use the "smooth" property

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm trying to execute the sample project from AR.js + A-FRAME using a custom gltf model projected to an image target using a-nft. The code is identical to [this example](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/image-tracking/) except for the model and image descriptors, and the smoothing function, which I've tried tinkering with the numbers, to no avail.

After some snooping around on here I found a few (quite old) posts mentioning interpolation. I want to get a grip first fully on the smooth property to see if I fully understand how that works, because no matter the numbers I input, the model keeps the same jittering. If necessary, I may implement interpolation, but I really wish that the smoothing would work :p.

TLDR: How to properly use the smooth property on AR.js | Other alternatives for smoother tracking.

Thanks in advance for reading and possibly answering!

Keywords: Image Target, AR.js, A-FRAME, gltf model, jittering, shaking, vibrating, bug.